# Dynamics AX 2012 R3: Penny Difference on invoice voucher

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have create an invoice with invoice amount = 96.63

Purchase order: create with one line with amount = 72.24 (with TAX 20%)
Header charges on Purchase order = 5.96 (with TAX 20%)

In the invoice register when I select the purchase order and put the invoice amount 96.63 it shows me TAX(20%) = 16.11

96.63 - 16.11 = 80.52

if I calculate the tax on 80.52 its 14.91 and tax on header charges is 1.19 so the total tax = 16.10 and because of this calculation it show tax 16.10 on invoice voucher entry.

why there is one penny difference ?

Answer (score 3):

It can be because of currency rounding off setup in the GL parameters, you can check that at

```
GL->Setup->GL parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate tax line by line and summing up may give a total different from if tax is calculated on the total. Penny differences are to be expected.